How to login to Azure Container Registry using Podman?
I would like to log in to the Azure Container Registry (ACR) using Podman CLI. I have obtained the admin username and password from Access key menu. I tried to log in using this command:
sudo podman login xyzabc.azurecr.io -u <user> -p <password>

However, I got the following error:

Error: logging into "xyzabc.azurecr.io": invalid username/password


An alternative way to log in to Azure Container Registry is to generate an access token first:
az acr login --name xyzabc --expose-token

The output will be like as follows:
{
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIs....",
  "loginServer": "xyzabc.azurecr.io"
}

To login, copy the access token and use the default username:
sudo podman login -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -p <token> xyzabc.azurecr.io


Note: The token expires after 3 hours, therefore you need to regenerate it.

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli
https://matthiasguentert.net/how-to-log-into-an-azure-container-registry-using-podman-cli/

